# CSS, Responsive DIVs

Tags: html, css, responsive

i'm trying to achieve something like that :

[image: What i'm trying to achieve]

1st you must know it should be full-screen, that's why I use %.

So far i've only been able to make the video stay 16:9 whatever the width of my screen is. I also been able to create the two lighter blues divs, but they don't automaticaly fit the space between the video and the footer.

I've also made the red divs.

Now i'm wondering how I can make the little blue divs fit the space, because right now they are not appearing at all and the only way to show them is to set a fixed high, which is not what i'm looking for. Also I wonder how I can make the second figure, for width screens.

Here is my code : http://codepen.io/EzhnoFR/pen/KNMBGO

```
<div id="aszone">
</div>

<div id="pbzone">

        <div id="pgzone">
            <video width="100%" preload="none" autoplay="true">
      <!-- MP4 for Safari, IE9, iPhone, iPad, Android, and Windows Phone 7 -->
            <source type="video/mp4" src="http://brunotarhan.fr/intro.mp4" />

        </div>

        <div id="ppzone">

            <div id="pp1">  
            </div>

            <div id="pp2">
            </div>

        </div>

</div>

<div id="gzone">
</div>

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div{
    border: 0px solid black;
}

video{
    width:100%;  !important;
}

#aszone, #gzone{
    height: 10%;
    background-color: grey;
    background-size: cover;

}

#gzone{
  height: 10%;
  bottom: 0;
  position:absolute;
}

#pbzone{
  height: 50%;
    position: relative;

}

#ppzone{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}

#pp1{
    width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}

#pp2{
    width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
    float:right;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#pgzone{

    background-image: url(screenfiles/bg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    border: 0px; !important
}
```

Comment: Post some code, not just images. However, this is fairly easy, so I don't really understand the problem...? You use @media-queries to change the behavior, and change around floats and sizes for the two (well, three) divs in question (all the blue ones). The red ones are the same either way, so shouldn't need any changing.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Yes I forgot the code indeed. I think it will be ok for the figure 2. But i'm wondering about how to fit the two blues div inside the space between the video and the footer

Comment: `float: left; max-width: 50%;` should do it, really.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie It does indeed, for the width, but not for the height.

Comment: Do you know the content? If not, you will have to set either a set height, or a max-height / min-height combo

Comment: No I don't know the content. Ok I understand how I should work, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Flex-box. If u give all blue ones a container, and change from 1 `flex-direction: column;` to 2 `flex-direction: row;` and add a container for the lighter blue ones and change the opposit way you have your desired layout.

Comment: Thank you Jojo. The main problem I have is to make the two little blues div fit between the footer and the video, do you have any suggestions ?